# Moving DFP ads post document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-dfp

We have a responsive site with a content area and sidebar. The sidebar goes below the content area when the site responds or is loaded on a mobile. The issue is that the mrec at the top of the sidebar is now far too low on the page and we need to make it higher in the dom.

So, pre render I pop a few divs in like this

```
<div class="ad-inject-ad ad-mrec2"></div>
```

That can be mrec1 through 3 depending on page, position, etc.

I also wrap my sidebar mrecs in identifiable classes, eg `ad-medrec2` so I can then move them when on mobile

```
$('.sidebar .ad-medrec2').appendTo('.ad-inject-ad.ad-mrec2')
```

This works a charm.

BUT, 60 - 70% of the time the ads disappear. The structure remains, you can see the container div is 300+ px tall where the ad *should* be, but the ad is gone.

I've tried using the `refresh()` method in DFP as well as the `display()` method. It seems though that the ad *is* displayed, but not visible. I lose the visibility on the ad, not the ad itself.

I've read that this can be caused by iframe's and their inability to reset state. But, I'm not sure the state needs to be refreshed.

And, why does it all work a third of the time?

What can I do here?

**EDIT**

I've also looked at the DFP jQuery plugin but would prefer to not load *another* script if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have this working at quite a high success rate now.

Firstly, I move the ad.

```
$('.sidebar .ad-medrec2').appendTo('.ad-inject-ad.ad-mrec2');
```

Then, I work out what the ad container's id and slot is called, delete the contents of the div and call the `googletag` function again to repopulate.

```
mrec2_id = $('.ad-medrec2').attr('id');
mrec2_slot_name = mrec2_id.substr(0, mrec2_id.indexOf('-wrapper'))
$('#' + mrec2_slot_name).children().remove();
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag.display(mrec2_slot_name);
});
```

This is working well. BUT, I'm afraid of this loading the ad twice. Until I can come up with a better option, I'll continue doing this.

Comment: Attention : Relocating an iframe (DFP uses iframes in async mode) results the iframe refresh. That means a second request to ad server.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a second adunit on your page ? 
You could use the DFP function defineSizeMapping to render the correct ad depending on the window size.

Comment: Nice! I'll give this a go and report back. Do you have any code examples? The Google docs are terrible.

Comment: Here is [Googles doc on the subject](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en).

You will find example that those exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I'll give it a go and report back

Answer (score 1):

You can use changeCorrelator (GPT References) to reload an ad without getting new impression count.

```
// This call to refresh fetches a new ad for slot1, without changing the
// correlator.
googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1], {changeCorrelator: false});

// This call to refresh fetches a new ad for each slot, without changing
// the correlator.
googletag.pubads().refresh(null, {changeCorrelator: false});
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference